# Why a value of type Datetime becomes '01/01/0001 00:00:00' when received?

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime, c#-4.0

I have very peculiar kind of an issue which is driving me nuts for the last so many months and i come back again and again in hope that I will fix it but cannot.

I have a web service written in c#. I pass it a date but it comes NULL. There are other data fields which are coming ok but this comes as `'01/01/0001 00:00:00'`.

```
private System.DateTime rEQ_STARTField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date")]
public System.DateTime REQ_START {
    get {
        return this.rEQ_STARTField;
    }
    set {
        this.rEQ_STARTField = value;
    }
}
```

When it is received by the method it becomes like '01/01/0001 00:00:00'.

**Sending: (From client)**

```
notif.REQ_START = dtRequestStartDate.Value.Date
```

`REQ_START` value is `3/4/2020`.

I am using Forms.DateTimePicker at client's end but that's not the problem, no matter whatever I assign to it via any tool, it becomes '01/01/0001 00:00:00' once received.

Update:

Upon deserializing I found that the REQ_Start is not even getting transmitted. It's not even in the payload. Why?

Comment: Are you transporting that value through XML? What *is* the value in the XML - is the problem in writing or reading?

Comment: In reading. Only for this field.

Comment: What's the raw XML element that is getting deserialized to this DateTime?

Comment: it is getting disappeared when I deserialized

Comment: I mean, the webservice is not even receiving it

Comment: What we are trying to find out is what the transport data is that your webservice is getting. Is that date already missing there, then it is a send problem. You should also provide some more code in your question: how are you sending this and how are you receiving it?

Comment: By the way, that 01/01/0001 is the default value of a DateTime field